# Android - avoid loading huge json data when not necessary

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a simple listview, which is loading data from a really huge JSON.

Currently I have it done like the example below - so I am pulling ALL the data from JSON. This is only an example, I have much more data there to assign to actorList:

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String url = "androidnews.json";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray actors = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i = 0; i < actors.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = actors.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setNazov(c.getString("name"));
                    actor.setPerex(c.getString("desc"));
                    actor.setPlace(c.getString("place"));
                    actor.setGps1(c.getString("gps1"));
                    actor.setGps2(c.getString("gps2"));
                    actor.setContact(c.getString("contact"));
                    actor.setinfo(c.getString("info"));

                    //and much more data from JSON

               actorsList.add(actor);

                }
```

However, it is working fine, but I think it is loading all the data for no reason.

Because in the listview I will use only title and description and all the other data will be passed only to the onclick activity of each item.

So I thought I will pass to onclick activity only the item's name, and in the other activity I will call a PHP file, which according this name as parameter will generate JSON with all other data, which will only be used in the other activity.

Am I doing this a better way?

I really don't think it's usefull to load all the unnecessary data when I will use only some of them.

So - actually there will be 2 jsons, one smaller for the listview and one for the details, but the second one will be called ONLY when user clicks some item in listview, so not everytime with the listview.

Comment: can you act on server?

Comment: yes, that PHP will be on my server, so I can handle the passed parameter there and generate a json

Comment: so yeah, the best way is to send only needed data for the first call, then when the user click on a particular item you can request updated data to your server